# List operation in StateNotifier Riverpod

Tags: flutter, list, dart, riverpod

I wish you all the best.

I got a problem about the list operation in riverpod. i have a lot of variables in the state and need to update its `count`:

```
class FooController extends StateNotifier<FooState> {
  final Ref ref;
  FooController (this.ref):super(const FooState());
  void addMore(int index){
    final cache = List<FooItem>.from(state.items);
    final removed = cache.removeAt(index);
    cache.insert(index, removed.copyWith(count: removed.count +1));
    //to trigger rebuild :
    state = state.copyWith(items: cache);
  }
}
```

even with lazy loading `ListView.builder`, its still "expensive" to rebuild this, and make ui flicker. (some Latex, custom painter, animation, etc).

i tried changing `int` to `ValueNotifier`

```
class FooState {
  final List<FooItem> items;
  const FooState({this.items = const []});
  FooState copyWith({List<FooItem>? items,}) {
    return FooState(items: items ?? this.items);
  }
}

class FooItem {
  final String data;
  ////final int count;
  final ValueNotifier<int> count;
  FooItem({ required this.data, required this.count});
  FooItem copyWith({String? data,int? count}) {
    return FooItem(
      data: data ?? this.data,
      ////count: count ?? this.count,
      count: this.count,
    );
  }
}
```

and the operation goes like this:

```
void addMore(int index){
    state.items[index].count.value += 1;
  }
```

but, this `ValueNotifier` class need to `dispose`. It's my concern that this change will be more expensive than before. what is the best way to do this? thank you in advance.